# Spring MVC RESTful multiple view - 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, view, restful-architecture

I have a web app which has JSPs as a view. But now I am trying to implement a RESTful in the same web app. I created a new controller, where will be my RESTful(I am not sure if it makes sense yet).

I have found some examples by internet and I have been trying to make my RESTful following these examples.

When I access my RESTful URL it return me **404 Not Found**. I took a look at in some questions similars here in stackoverflow and tried to change some XML configurations, but it does not works, so far.

```
When I access:
URL: localhost:8080/restfultest/rest/suggestions/11
returns me: 404.

When I access:
URL: localhost:8080/restfultest/loginForm
Returns me the correct JSP page.
```

I think, maybe I need to set up the XML to be compatible with both kinds, RESTful and a common web app, but I am not sure, and I do not know exactly how to do it.

Thanks and follows my codes:

My web.xml

```
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>

        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-context.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.restfultest." />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
        <property name="contentType" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <util:list id="beanList">
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </util:list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>


    <mvc:interceptors>

        <bean class="com.restfultest.interceptor.AutorizadorInterceptor"></bean>
        <bean class="com.restfultest.interceptor.ConnectionInterceptor"></bean>

    </mvc:interceptors>

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

Controller

```
public class SuggestionController {

    @Autowired
    private SuggestionService suggestionService;

    @Autowired
    private View view;

    private static final String DATA_FIELD = "data";
    private static final String ERROR_FIELD = "error";

    private static final String CONTENT_RANGE_HEADER = "Content-Range";
    private static final String ACCEPT_JSON = "Accept=application/json";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/suggestions/{suggestionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers=ACCEPT_JSON)
    public ModelAndView getSuggestion(@PathVariable("suggestionId") String suggestionId) {

        Suggestion suggestion = null;

        if (isEmpty(suggestionId) || suggestionId.length() < 5) {
            String sMessage = "Error invoking getSuggestion - Invalid suggestion Id parameter";
            return createErrorResponse(sMessage);
        }

        try {

            suggestion = suggestionService.getSuggestionById(suggestionId);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            String sMessage = "Error invoking getSuggestion. [%1$s]";
            return createErrorResponse(String.format(sMessage, e.toString()));
        }

        return new ModelAndView(view, DATA_FIELD, suggestion);
    }

    private ModelAndView createErrorResponse(String sMessage) {
        return new ModelAndView(view, ERROR_FIELD, sMessage);
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(String s_p) {
        return (null == s_p) || s_p.trim().length() == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your SuggestionController should have a @Controller annotation on it so Spring will treat it as a Controller (it should also be in the com.restfultest package).

Now I'm not sure if this matters butin the spring-context.xml where you have

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.restfultest." />
```

I've never seen it with a dot at the end.  So you might consider removing it, but it might not make a difference.