# Separating GUI and DAO via REST Webservices and Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, hibernate, rest

I have a general question about the correct (or maybe: the best) way to handle data from GUI to DAO.

I built a project where GUI input is being validated and sent directly to a DAO class which handles (via [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29)) the database updates/inserts.

Now I decided to split DAO and GUI up into two separate projects and use a REST WS with Spring integration to handle the data. I considered this, because I thought this might be a good idea for future projects (advantage of course being the complete separation of the GUI from DAO).

For the moment I have a bit of a problem of making this all work ([Spring error creating bean xStreamMarshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354984/spring-error-creating-bean-xstreammarshaller)). But before I try unnecessarily I wanted to know: Is that really a good approach?

Is this really a correct way or am I doing something completely unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this post can be useful for you: 
[Spring MVC RESTful multiple view - 404 Not Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095666/spring-mvc-restful-multiple-view-404-not-found)

I like the idea to work with restful, because you can really split the application not just in the back-end, but in the front-end as well. This way you can just get JSON in your javascript. But of course each case is different each other.

Follows a video about the subject: [Designing a REST-ful API Using Spring 3](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/REST-API-Spring-MVC)

Comment: thank you for your answer! I hope I can figure out how to make this application run with 2 seperate projects!